# When product of matrix and vector equals 0, why does product of matrix, it's transpose and vector also equals 0?

Tags: linear-algebra

I've got a matrix A and a vector s

When Av = 0, why does A*As = 0 and also s*A*As = 0?

A* is transposed matrix A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace the hypothesis $A s = 0$ in each of the expressions you ask about.